# Having trouble using react-native-video on react-native-tvos@^0.63.4-0

Tags: react-native, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-tv, react-native-video

## Bug

We are using this library to build an application for **AndroidTV** which is heavily relied on Video streaming , so we decided to use this library and see how it goes.

**we only use HLS (m3u8) video formats for the application.**

we used **ExoPlayer** and everything seemed to be fine , but when users started installing the application on off-brand **AndroidBoxes** , we got flooded with bug reports with all of them consisting of one particular problem , "*Video player is not working*".
we started debuggin on multiple devices , including **Android Phones** , **AndroidTVs** , **Amazon Fire Stick** and **android boxes**.

we debugged using both *ExoPlayer* and *MediaPlayer* for some devices.

- and the result that we got is this :

  - **Android Phone**: both the *ExoPlayer* And *MediaPlayer* worked fine.
  - **AndroidTV**: *ExoPlayer* worked fine but when we tried to use *MediaPlayer* the video started getting desynced.
  - **Amazon Fire Stick**: *ExoPlayer* worked fine. (*did not test using MediaPlayer*)
  - **Android Box**: *ExoPlayer* did not work correctly , problems included 2x speed while we set it to 1 manually , having no sound and not working entirely. *MediaPlayer* on the other hand , seemed to work at first but after 30-40 minutes of use it`d be glitchy and run the video at 2 FPS.

### Platform

Which player are you experiencing the problem on:

- Android ExoPlayer
- Android MediaPlayer

### Environment info

React native info output:

```sh
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18363
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz 
    Memory: 3.36 GB / 11.90 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE       
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.11 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  4.1.0.0 AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882
    Visual Studio: 16.5.30011.22 (Visual Studio Community 2019)
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_282 - /c/Program Files/OpenJDK/openjdk-8u282-b08/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-native: Not Found
    react-native-tvos:  0.63.4-0
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Library version: ^5.1.1

### Steps To Reproduce

1. run `react-native init TestApp --template=react-native-tvos` .
2. run `npm i react-native-video` .
3. give the `<Video />` an HLS type video.
4. run `react-native run-android --variable=release` and install the apk file on the target platform.

### Expected behaviour

A solution or fix to Play the video smoothly on TV platforms .

*I opened an issue regarding this problem at the react-native-video github [here](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2411#issue-932387271).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed like our problem was with the encoding of our files, which made HLS files unstable.
If you want to use HLS in your app, make sure your encodings are standard and work on older devices.

Comment: How did you encoded your videos later to fix this? can you please share some info?